# Automatically generating images for an art show with deep learning software

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, algorithms, gan

My pursuit is to generate something like a grottesque(a kind of painting producing human-animals and plants hybrids).  I need to do something like this painting in order to create an art exhibition. I don't need that produced images are ordinate or beautiful, just monstrous images produced automatically by a computer. Can someone help me? And is it possible to do it in a month?

Comment: What's your question, how that relates to Data Science?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate morphed images and then scale any size. You can use [this](https://github.com/jembezmamy/morpher-js) or similar libraries.

Comment: You might try "neural style transfer" . This is not exactly morphing but you can get some very interesting results. There are a number of these on GITHUB so you might download one of the kernels and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough training examples and try something good, you can train Deep Convolutional Generative Adversarial Network using your input arts.

Further reads [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan).